# Google app engine for PHP does not load mysql

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, google-app-engine

i am completely new to Google app engine. Im trying to host my wordpress blog using app engine. I tried some simple PHP scripts with app engine and everything goes well. But when  i tried to load wordpress using app engine in my windows system, It is showing the error as,

`"Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress."`

So i printed the loaded extensions in PHP using the get_loaded_extensions() php function, which outputs as follows,

```
Array
(
    [0] => Core
    [1] => bcmath
    [2] => calendar
    [3] => ctype
    [4] => date
    [5] => ereg
    [6] => filter
    [7] => ftp
    [8] => hash
    [9] => iconv
    [10] => json
    [11] => mcrypt
    [12] => SPL
    [13] => odbc
    [14] => pcre
    [15] => Reflection
    [16] => session
    [17] => standard
    [18] => mysqlnd
    [19] => tokenizer
    [20] => zip
    [21] => zlib
    [22] => libxml
    [23] => dom
    [24] => PDO
    [25] => Phar
    [26] => SimpleXML
    [27] => wddx
    [28] => xml
    [29] => xmlreader
    [30] => xmlwriter
    [31] => cgi-fcgi
    [32] => mhash
)
```

which shows that mysql is not loaded and i couldn't find any way to install it seperately since app engine does not allows it. But in app engine's documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/), it is given that they are enabling mysql in app engine. So why the app engine not loading some extensions which is enabled by Google or is there any way to enable it manually? I don't know how to proceed further. Please help..

Note: I'm using Windows 7

Comment: Doesn't GAE uses your own php installation along with your php.ini configuration?

Comment: We can choose either by specifying the path..

Answer (score 1):

That looks like the output from php installed on your machine, not the php in the app engine production environment.

You should be able to configure mysql to run locally following the instructions here: -> http://php.net/manual/en/mysql.installation.php

To see what extensions are available in production, run get_loaded_extensions() in the php shell here -> http://php-minishell.appspot.com/

Comment: I don't know, how to install it locally to made it work with google app engine. Because there is no dll files associated with app engine. So i don't know how to made it to work with it :(